# What percent of people in the United States are vaccinated against measles?

Tags: vaccination, public-health, measles

I am researching measles vaccination rates.  Almost every source I have found focuses on immunization coverage among *children* (of various ages).  However, I am curious what the overall *population* immunization coverage rates are.

Can anyone find a published estimate of the percent of the **total** population of the United States (including children and adults, citizens and immigrants) that is vaccinated against measles?

Comment: I am researching your question: indeed, so far I have found zero data on adult/general population measles vax rates or immune status rates. These data are conspicuously absent, suggesting that this question is not thought to merit research dollars at entities such as the CDC, WHO, or NIH et al. This is likely, given that immunity is assumed for adults born before 1957, the highly successful eradication of endemic measles in the U.S., and studies showing immunity to be complete/ lifelong in 99% of fully immunized children. I have 2 emails out requesting data: I will keep you posted!

Comment: Another contributing factor behind the lack of data is that adults born after 1956 often: a) don’t know if they were vaccinated as a child, don’t possess their immunization records from childhood, or those records are lost / not available; b) the type of vaccine they received as a child is unknown (some early vaccines were of indeterminate efficacy.)  Therefore proving immunity in the adult population would likely involve a costly study built around obtaining antibody titers - which seems unlikely to be considered worth the funds, given the several reasons outlined above...